# My scrolled navbar returns to default when I reload my page in the middle of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My scrolled navbar return to default when i reload my page in the middle of the page

[Here is my website photos look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SanCg.png)

My javascript codes :

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $scrol = $(document).scrollTop();

         if ($scrol > 50 ) {
            $('.header').addClass('header6');
            $('.logo').addClass('logo5');
            $('.about').addClass('about5');
            $('.about:hover').addClass('about5:hover');
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar5');
            $('.nav').addClass('nav5');
         }
        else{
            $('.header').removeClass('header6');
            $('.logo').removeClass('logo5');
            $('.about').removeClass('about5');
            $('.about:hover').removeClass('about5:hover');
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar5');
            $('.nav').removeClass('nav5');
        }
    });
});
```

i wait answers 
THANK YOU

Comment: I guess the problem is, your classes are being applied only after you start scrolling. You should apply them once, on load, without need for scrolling first.

Comment: As an aside, you're caching the wrong things. `$scrol` is being cached despite having no need for it (it's used once per run), and on the other hand, `$('.header')`, `$('.logo')` etc. are not being cached when that would be a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run your function when the page loads to update your header :

I also added some modifications to optimize your code, as stated by @jeremy-thille

```
function updateScroll(obj){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
        obj.header.addClass('header6'); //Use the previously stored JQuery requests
        obj.logo.addClass('logo5');
        obj.about.addClass('about5');
        obj.navbar.addClass('navbar5');
        obj.nav.addClass('nav5');
    }
    else{
        obj.header.removeClass('header6');
        obj.logo.removeClass('logo5');
        obj.about.removeClass('about5');
        obj.navbar.removeClass('navbar5');
        obj.nav.removeClass('nav5');
    }
}

$(function(){ //New way to wait for the document to be loaded
    //Store JQuery calls to reduce processing time
    var storedObjects = {
        header: $('.header'),
        logo: $('.logo'),
        about: $('.about'),
        navbar: $('.navbar'),
        nav: $('.nav')
    };

    updateScroll(storedObjects); // Will update your header

    $(window).scroll(updateScroll(storedObjects));
});
```